# Jinja2 "include" statement not working with Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, template-engine

I am developing a python web app on Google App Engine using Jinja2 as the template manager. In one of my pages, I am using the "include" statement to inject another HTML page into the main page. It does work fine on my local machine (PyCharm 5.0.4 IDE), however, when uploading the app to production, it breaks saying the template was not found.

This is the include statement:

```
{% include '/widgets/transaction/add-transaction-modal/add-transaction-modal.html' %}
```

I also tried putting the complete URL by adding http://my_app_id.appspot.com/ to the include statement, but still get the same error.

This is my Jinja2 configuration:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir), 'templates')),
extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])
```

This is the app.yaml:

```
- url: /widgets
  static_dir: app/templates/widgets
```

This is the folder structure:

```
+ APP
    + static
        - css
        - js 
        - img
    + templates
        + pages
            - dashboard.html (contains de include statement to the widget)
        + widgets
            - add-transaction-modal.html
            - add-transaction-modal.js
```

This is really odd since it works just fine on my local development server. My guess is that this issue is related to some specifics of App Engine PROD environemnt than Jinja2 itself.

Any thoughts on what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work without the leading slash in the include path?

Comment: What does your `app.yaml` look like?  If `/widgets/transaction/add-transaction-modal` is inside a static directory, those files get served differently than the non-static files (by default).  Where is the template that has the `include` statement located?

Comment: @DanielRoseman even removing the leading slash did not fix it

Comment: @mgilson I guess you are right about the static directory. I updated the question with my app.yaml content related to the widget directory and also added the folder structure I am working with

Comment: Daniel is correct.  You can't have templates that your code needs to read in a static directory.  It must be deployed with your code (it is code).

Comment: @TimHoffman thanks for the clarification. GAE is pretty new to me so I am still struggling to figure out how to work with it. I guess I understand why the issue but didn't get how to fix it. If I just remove the widgets from app.yaml, it stops working and returns 500. Still, I don't get why this works fine locally - it is supposed to fail just like in prod

Comment: So you need to look at the stack trace in the console. This will tell you what the cause of the error is.

Comment: @FabioMoggi -- What happens if you remove that section from app.yaml entirely?